# CSS Grid в 2018?

Tags: css, вёрстка, css-grid

Недавно разобрался в CSS Grid, и понял что это лучшее для меня решение в плане позиционирования элементов.

Единственное что меня тревожит это то 81% пользователей смогут нормально пользоваться таким сайтом, и я задаюсь вопросом - стоит ли использовать CSS Grid в верстке на заказ или еще рано?

Comment: Пока рано, лучше флексы

Comment: в интернете можно найти статьи про то, как добиться приемлимого отображения в браузерах, которые не поддерживают гриды https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/11/css-grid-supporting-browsers-without-grid/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Это всё зависит от требований.

У меня были несколько проектов, когда не надо было поддерживать мобильные устройства. Или просто сказали, что проект для внутреннего пользования, "пусть работает только в Chrome". Также бывают проекты, когда нужно поддерживать только топовые браузеры.

Уточните требования у заказчика и если он разрешает не поддерживать браузеры, которые без поддержки CSS Grid, то почему бы и нет.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - использовать grid в тех браузерах, которые это поддерживают, используя директиву @supports. В остальных флексы.
Вот интересная статься на эту тему http://css-live.ru/articles/verstka-prostoj-setki-s-folbekami-ispolzuyushhimi-direktivu-supports-feature-queries.html